# Which webservice engine can I use over tomcat 3.3.1?

Tags: java, web-services

So, here's the deal: I'm developing a Java webservice to be hosted by an MFP (multifunctional printer). Unfortunatelly, its software specs are pretty low (a custom VM that supports development with Java up to 1.3 and tomcat 3.3.1). I'm pretty used to create webservices using Eclipse (Ganymede), Java 6 and higher Tomcat versions with Axis 2 webservice runtime, but I'm stuck with Tomcat 3.3.1 that doesn't even support Axis 1. Furtermore, I can't seem to find out what engine the printer itself uses (I know it supports webservice hosting), so any runtime that can be used along with Tomcat 3.3.1 will be very welcome for testing purposes. The printer specification doesn't cover webservice development, so I'm in the dark here. Little help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure *Tomcat 3* does not support *Axis 1*? Axis 1 should work with Java 1.3 ("[Note also that Axis client and server requires Java 1.3 or later.](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/install.html#Introduction)"), but I never tried myself.

Downloading the latest version (1.4), you can read "JDK Version - 1.3.1+" under *Recommended Environment*. Good luck with your antique environment.